# Add Multiple User to 1 group in debian10

Tags: linux, debian

vi userlist.txt

```
Tom
Josh
Noah
```

vi addgroup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in 'cat userlist.txt'
do
sudo usermod -a -G vncuser $user
done
```

sh addgroup.sh

```
Usage usermod [options] LOGIN
```

how do i solve this "Usage usermod [options] LOGIN" error? 
sorry i am a beginner for this, thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping on "cat userlist.txt" not on the content of the file.
That means $user will be equal to "cat" then "userlist.txt".
You could add a log line like:

```
echo "Adding user '$user' to group vncuser"
```

How to fix it:
Use either backtick like  `command` or dollar parentheses format like $(command).
I prefer the second one because it's easier to read.

```
for user in $(egrep -v "^#|^$" userlist.txt); do
  echo "Adding user '$user' to group 'vncuser'"
  sudo usermod -a -G vncuser $user
done
```

What did I do here? I used the egrep to filter  lines beginning with a # and empty lines.

Comment: Yes this is just the code i need, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Double quote each line variable:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  sudo usermod -a -G vncuser "$line"
done <userlist.txt
```

Then do a `chmod +x filename.sh` before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

First step: You need to use either backticks (not sinqle quotes) or just the `$()` operator

```
for user in $(cat userlist.txt) do
  sudo usermod -a -G vncuser $user
done
```

In addition to that, you might get empty lines, so

```
for user in $(cat userlist.txt) do
  test -n "$user" && sudo usermod -a -G vncuser $user
done
```

And finally do away with `cat

```
while read user ; do
  test -n "$user" && sudo usermod -a -G vncuser $user
done <userlist.txt
```